# Changing Locations, please help?

Tags: whonix

I have been trying to figure out how to change the location because it always thinks I am in Europe.  Is there a way to change the location to what you want?  For example, I want the computer to think i am in paris or if I want it to look like florida.  How can I do this?  If anybody has the answer, state like i am a 5 year old.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you using, Tor Browser?

Comment: You can edit your `torrc` file, but you'll only be able to change to a specific country, or to a specific exit relay. If you wanted a particular city, you'd have to find a relay in that city by checking the IP addresses of all relays. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit

Comment: Thanks Ron, for helping but I am still lost.  I understand the torrc file needs to be edited but how?  more to the point what examples can I use to understand the entry and exit point of Tor.  still tad confused.  thanks.